# Should X-UA-Compatible be used to reduce the time to parse/render a HTML page?

Tags: html, performance, internet-explorer, http-headers, x-ua-compatible

In Internet Explorer (8, 9, or 10) is it faster for the browser to parse/render a HTML page if I specify the [`X-UA-Compatible` response header](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676915(v=vs.85).aspx) with the value, `IE=edge,chrome=1` vs. not including any reference to `X-UA-Compatible`?  In my case I am 100% sure that IE will not enter info compatibility mode for rendering, so I am looking to see if adding the header will improve the load of my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe this will have any effect on the performance of IE's rendering engine Trident whatsoever. Even if it did, we probably don't even realize it. For all you know, the few extra bytes in your response headers and/or your page markup may end up being the bigger overhead!

Take note that specifying `chrome=1` will cause any version of IE starting from IE6 with Google Chrome Frame installed to switch over to the plugin, rendering Trident irrelevant for the most part.